# Slow string http request with Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I´m currently recording lots of data from an accelerometer via blutooth from a microcontroller into an arraylist with which i processed to graph, label and trim if needed.

Later, i send this information via string http request using volley in a *for loop* to a url that catches this information and stores it into a PostgresQL database.

The current problem is that if i record lets say 4500 values in 3 minutes the application takes roughly 4 minutes to send all the information. Since im relativly new i don´t know if there is a better method or if there is something wrong with what i coded.

The code is as follows:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Graphs.this);

for (int i = porIntLeft; i < porIntRight; i++) {

    String url = "*URL GOES HERE*/new?x=" + String.valueOf(ValoresX.get(i)) + "&y=" + String.valueOf(ValoresY.get(i)) + "&z=" + String.valueOf(ValoresZ.get(i)) + "&label=\"" + Label + "\"";


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

I have this running inside a thread since at the same time im displaying a ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sending 4500 HTTP requests? Of course it takes a lot of time. Instead collect your data and put it in a json document for instance. And send that document in one HTTP request (of course if you can change your backend to allow that).

Comment: Intresting, if you know of any documentation i could read i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use getBody inside the StringRequest and use a Map to add your values and send x ammount every so often. But the server whould need to be redesigned to handle json, and you would have to do away with the URI get method your currently using. Or you could design this method to send all the data, seperate each value by some char, not sure which would be applicable to a URI though.